# Characteristic Polynomial linear math

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$
be a matrix of complex numbers. Find the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)$ of $A$ and compute $\chi_A(A)$.

I just wanted to confirm that I did this correctly.

Tha answer I have is:
$$\chi_A(t)= \det\begin{pmatrix}a-t&b\\c&d-t\end{pmatrix}
=(a-t)(d-t)-bc
=ad-bc-at-dt+t^2.
$$
Thus
$$
\chi_A(A)=
\begin{pmatrix}a-(ad-bc-at-dt+t^2)&b\\c&d-(ad-bc-at-dt+t^2)\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this the right thinking?

Answer (score 1):

No, your thinking does not seem right.
Try thinking of the following problem: If you have a polynomial $p(x)$, how to make sense of $p(A)$ for a square matrix $A$?

You found that the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\chi_A(t)
=
(ad-bc)-(a+d)t+t^2.
$$
Now we can plug $A$ in this polynomial (not in the determinant expression that generated the polynomial!) to get
$$
\chi_A(A)
=
(ad-bc)I-(a+d)A+A^2.
$$
This is just formally taking $t=A$.
You should now calculate the square of $A$ and add up the terms.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why is this answer different from mine. However I don't care if you care so much about reputation, i'm deleting my answer but not my downvote.

Comment: @Ale, it is not a matter of reputation. If I comment that something is missing from your answer and give a new answer, I certainly don't mean that you should remove yours. I just wanted to give an answer in my own words, and I thought it would have been a bad idea to edit your answer too much. It's not that different from yours, I know. I think your answer was valuable, and I'm sorry if you were upset by my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general for a matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix},\quad \in M(n \times n; \Bbb{C})$$
we have that  the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)$ is
\begin{align*}
X_A(t):&=\text{det}(A-t\Bbb{1})\\
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}a-t&b\\c&d-t\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(a-t)(d-t)-bc\\
&=t^2-(a+d)t+ad-bc\\
&=t^2-\text{tr}(A)t+\text{det}(A)
\end{align*}
By the theorem of [Cayley-Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we have that

$$\chi_A(t) = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^2-(ad-bc)\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}+(ad-bc)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I think the point was to prove the Cayley-Hamilton theorem by hand in the case of $2\times2$ matrices, not to use it as a black box.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I know that, but there is not so much left to do. I've already said the OP that to compute $\chi_A(t)$ he need to evaluate $$\chi_A(t) = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^2-(ad-bc)\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}+(ad-bc)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

I think that he can do this, since he already have talked about characteristic polinomial he has surely have seen multiplication of matrices.